# Serverless framework for APIGateway deployment with HTTP endpoint invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, automation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to acheive APIGateway deployment using serverless framework having an http endpoint invocation.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.

```
functions:
  TestAPI:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /test
          method: get
          authorizer: aws_iam
          integration: http
          cors: false
          request:
            uri: 'http://karthibalu.simplesite.com'
            passThrough: NEVER
            template:
              application/json: '{}'
            parameters:
              headers:
                X-Request-Id: false
          response:
            statusCodes:
              200:
                pattern: '' 
                headers:
                  Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000'"
              500:
                pattern: '500' 
                headers:
                  Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000'"
                  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'Original Url'"
```